# XML Layout Misbehavior with Eclipse-ADT

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, adt, android-xml

I am facing something strange issue with Android XML Layout Editor.

Whenever I am switching from Graphical Layout to Code Layout, It shows everything perfectly and when I'll click or move up down via keyboard arrow keys, it behaves strange and part of xml line are becoming visible/invisible.

Xml code is there, its not changing.

Have a look at attached video link.
http://screencast.com/t/rY1gKPY9vn

**My current Config :**
Eclipse SDK
Version: 3.7.2
Build id: M20120208-0800

Android Development Toolkit
Version: 20.0.3.v201208082019-427395

**Update :**
issue is still there with Eclipse with 4.2 also

Comment: i am also facing a similar issue on my eclipse juno

Comment: I am too facing the similar Issue.I get through by closing the XML file and again reopening it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a known issue and I have also faced this strange issue with Eclipse, the solution to it is to close the XML file and open it again. If that doesn't work, restarting Eclipse should also solve it.

Comment: yes i don't think so that anybody really knows the cause or test scenario to recreate this bug that's why it's called a strange issue..:) the good thing is that there is working solution for it.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue for a long time and sometimes it helps just to save the file. If not, reopening always helps.

Answer (score 0):

the same issue i was facing in XML file. The solution is either reopen the file. And the perfect solution is upgrade your eclipse version to JUNO. That will not create such type of irritation problem..

Have fun.

Comment: Eclipse SDK
Version: 4.2.1
Build id: M20120914-1800
Updated to this version for long still having the same issue. It didn't solve the issue